# Should I warn that drop down filters are mandatory?

Tags: filter, dropdown, error-message, drop-down-list

When dealing with various drop down list of options, with one acting as a filter to another and the last one being the desired option *per se*, it is more advisable to treat all drop downs as obligatory or just the final one used?

---

Let me set an example:

```
Country: [ select a country ⌄ ]
State:   [ select a state   ⌄ ]
City:    [ select a city    ⌄ ]
```

At first only the country drop down is loaded. As the user selects the country the state one got loaded. Finally, when the user selects a state, the city one is loaded.

Like: United States → Illinois → Chicago.

In the end what is really needed by the form is that the user is located at Chicago city.

If the user attempts to submit without selecting a state or a country, should it be warned that they are obligatory or just that the city it is (since the two first act as mere filters)?

Comment: If you can give defaults to your from. Whenever user go to from City name get automatically filled. For example https://accounts.google.com/SignUp in which country name is automatically filled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of city selector the better solution could be autocomplete control, which has features:

- quick city selection
- disambiguation elimination (e.g. [duplicatename cities in the USA](http://voices.yahoo.com/duplicate-name-cities-usa-kind-towns-3638487.html))
- removes national specificity (some countries don't have states, etc.)
- less cognitive load, as user concentrates on city entering
- unobtrusive filtering: [**City** → Country → State] vs [Country → State → **City**]

[image]

---

In your current interaction (select → load) it seems impossible to skip Country and State fields. Anyway, filters look like hierarchical fields, and there are no cues of skip is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**City** is mandatory input and it depends on **State** and state in turn depends on **Country**. So, if user submits without selecting Country or State or City and there are no defaults set to these fields, system should warn that these are obligatory.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto **@Alexey**'s answer, I would suggest allowing users to enter the City, State *or* the city's Postal Code. Once a user's focus moves away from the location form field, format the location correctly or prompt the user if more information is required. For example:

> - User enters enough data, such as **London, UK**, and this is reformatted upon the user changing focus away from the form field to **London, United Kingdom**.
> - User doesn't enter enough data, such as **London**, and then is presented with a list of possible options that they could have meant:
>
>   - London, United Kingdom
>   - London, OH, United States

In order for this to work though you'll need a pretty robust geo-data library to reference in real-time.